как правильно объявить переменную в telebot?
Хотелось бы передать значение user id на свою страницу в качестве параметра GET при нажатии на кнопку ReplyKeyboardMarkup...
Решил что при нажатии кнопки start, значение user id запишу в переменную и сформирую ссылку в:
types.WebAppInfo("https://site/index.html"+"?"+str(usid))
Но при запуске и попытке начать чат, получаю ошибку...
NameError: name 'usid' is not defined
Как это исправить и каким образом, возможна отправка при нажатии на кнопку ReplyKeyboardMarkup?
Прошу Вашей помощи.
    def webAppKeyboard(): #создание клавиатуры с webapp кнопкой
   keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True, is_persistent=False) #создаем клавиатуру
   kurs = types.WebAppInfo("https://site/index.html"+"?"+str(usid))
   one_butt = types.KeyboardButton(text="КУРС", web_app=kurs)
   #one_butt = types.KeyboardButton(text="КУРС")
   keyboard.add(one_butt)
   
   return keyboard #возвращаем клавиатуру


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_fun(message):
   bot.send_message( message.chat.id, 'Привет', parse_mode="Markdown", reply_markup=webAppKeyboard()) 
   **global usid**
   usid = message.from_user.id
   print(usid)


Может стоит питон подучить, а потом ботов делать? К тому еще и с веб-аппами

В обычной программе, я объявил бы переменную в любом месте (не внутри функции) и она считалась бы глобальной, а здесь почему-то не работает...

Потому что она внутри функции, наверное? В телеграм боте нельзя использовать глобальные переменные, зачем вообще хранить ид юзера, если он в каждом объекте message?

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно использовать объект message, внутри функции webAppKeyboard() (приведённой в коде выше)?

ну, передай этой функции аргумент и при вызове передай туда id полученное из message
